# How to correctly set the spellfile in VIM?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to use spellchecker in vim; if I want to add a word to the internal dictionary (so that it is not highlighted as wrong) by the ***zg*** command, it says `"option spellfile is not set"`.

I tried to type :`set spellfile=PATH.../.vim.spell`,

but I always get `"Invalid argument: spellfile=PATH.../.vim.spell"`. Any hint please?

I'm using linux Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Thanks for improving my formatting, I'm new at this forum.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot choose an arbitrary name. `:help 'spellfile'` says:

> It must end in ".{encoding}.add".

So, use a syntax like this (and ensure that the `spell` directory exists):

```
:set spellfile=~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
```

For encoding, check `:set encoding?` (Technically, it's the buffer-local `'fileencoding'` setting, but that most defaults to the former.)

Answer (score 12):

Maybe you should just do `mkdir ~/.vim`.

By default, the spell files are stored there. But if vim could not find that folder, it will complain with this error message.

Comment: In my case the ~/.vim folder was owned by root for some reason, causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was caused by surrounding the path with single quotes in my rc file. Remove the single quotes.